# Kodi addons : how can I cache / load datas?

Tags: python, caching, add-on, kodi

I’m writing a video addon that loads datas from a web API.

My problem is that, each time I access an (already) visited virtual folder, it loads the data again, while it could be cached - and it makes my addon slow.

Is there some core function to cache then get cached datas for Kodi addons ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can just store your request results in the Kodi data [folder](https://kodi.wiki/view/Kodi_data_folder)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such "core" function, so you need to implement your own caching mechanism. An addon has its "profile" directory where it can store its own arbitrary files. A profile directory path can be obtained the following way:

```
  import xbmcaddon
  import xbmcvfs

  profile_dir = xbmcvfs.translatePath(xbmcaddon.Addon().getAddonInfo('profile'))
```